# use WindowsIdentity/WindowsPrincipal to get SAML token for WS-Federation

Tags: c#, kerberos, adfs, wif, ws-federation

Is there a way to use the native WindowsIdentity/WindowsPrincipal inside of a C# application running on a corporate domain to be able to request a SAML token from the domain's ADFS server so that the C# application can then make subsequent calls to WS-Federation calls in a service provider that has been federated with the ADFS server?

Seems like we would use WIF to contact the ADFS server to get a token. Is there a way to supply a Kerberos ticket to the WIF, rather than using a username/password?

Looking at WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() I can see that the user is logged in using kerberos, but don't see how to configure the WIF call to ADFS to use kerberos to automatically get a SAML token without a username/password set of credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Does https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alikl/2011/09/30/how-to-use-ad-fs-endpoints-when-developing-claims-aware-wcf-services-using-wif/ help?

You should make sure you have an endpoint enabled that can do windows integrated auth via kerberos enabled. Something like /adfs/services/trust/2005/windowstransport or /adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport . You can check that via parsing the /adfs/services/trust/mex endpoint. Occasionally some of these endpoints are disabled by a sysadmin.

Using a kerberos ticket as the credential for the endpoint means your app needs to be running on corpnet with access to domain controllers so it can obtain a ticket for AD FS. If the app use is not required outside corpnet this might be OK for you. Else you need to consider how the app behaves/authenticates inside and outside corpnet.

Have a look at https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=4451 for samples but they'll need modifying based on version of WIF you plan to use as outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/guidelines-for-migrating-an-application-built-using-wif-3-5-to-wif-4-5

Lastly you should consider if its possible to use OpenID Connect and OAuth2.0 instead of WS-Federation/WS-Trust in your scenario. If yes, you should review the information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-scenarios-for-developers

Comment: Thank you. Will try some of this on Monday. Yes, we can try OpenID Connect. We were originally talking about SAML tokens for WS-Federation, just because the service provider is old and already supported SAML 2 for the UI. There's a willingness to try OpenID Connect though. We'll do a quick prototype of both just to understand them. Thanks for the help. I'll respond more after trying everything out.